# The address of the page which referred the user agent to the current page. when data is send by fsockopen

Tags: php, http-referer, fsockopen

HTTP_REFERER is not working.

from client  using fsockopen i am sending data to server. there i want to know the client address. 
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER' is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to send a referer header, i.e. `Referer: http://example.com/`.